# Quick & Easy: why won't this run?

Tags: java, arrays, parsing, netbeans, collections

```
//markParse is an Integer ArrayList
//ii is the number of elements in markParse
//analysis is a textArea in the program's design

int max = java.util.Collections.max(markParse);
int min = java.util.Collections.min(markParse);
int range = max - min;
int average = sumData/ii;

analysis.setText("Avg: " + average);
analysis.append("Max: " + max);
analysis.append("Min: " + min);
analysis.append("Range: " + range);
```

Hopefully this is enough code, as it is the only part of my program which has errors. When I run my program, this section calculates and displays the max/min value in the array list, average, and range. It is supposed to be implemented when I click a button (containing this code); however, nothing happens.

I'm fairly certain it has something to do with java.util.Collections statement, but am not sure. Please correct and/or explain.

Comment: Have you tried stepping into this code in a debugger?  Are you sure your button is actually calling this code?

Comment: I changed the code so it would simply print "dog" and it worked. So the button is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to also pass `null` as second parameter to the method:

```
int max = java.util.Collections.max(markParse, null);
int min = java.util.Collections.min(markParse, null);
```

Comment: Okay, I'm stumped - why would that make a difference?  If `null` is passed to `Collections.min(coll, comp)`, the only thing it does is return `Collections.min(coll)`.  Making this change seems like it would have no effect (beyond dealing with a compile issue if your `List` isn't actually a `List<T extends Comparable<? super T>>`.